# Create a user automatically

Tags: python, django

I have simple model where user writes some text and saves it, I need to add current user to this created object. Right now I have such code where user can be chosen manually, how do I make it automatically? I know about user=self.request.user, but I don't know how to use it in Models.
Sorry if this question is silly, I'm new to Django

```
class SomeText(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    keyword = models.TextField(verbose_name='Add your text here')
```

Comment: How do you authenticate the user? He should authenticate before adding text or getting the login information of the new user in creating new text.

Comment: What is the "current user"? where exactly are you trying to create an instance of this class? what have you tried specifically?

Comment: How are you creating the `SomeText` objects?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't provude much details, again, I'm new. Also English is not my native. So, current user - I meant the one who was logged in. So yeah, user who authenticated shoud be added automatically to new object. I'm creating SomeText object through admin page in browser(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign a user automatically user must be login. If user is already login then you can try the below code

In your **views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import SomeText
def assign(request):
   text=request.POST['text'] #It will coming from your HTML form (front end)
   user=reuqest.user
   obj=SomeText()
   obj.user=user
   obj.text=text
   obj.save()
   return HttpResponse("Text added!")
```

Comment: Please upvote if it's helpful. Thanks